# Set elements to their original state after manipulations

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, slidetoggle

So after you click the "Show Description" link [Here](http://gta4you.esy.es/test.php) It slides out the description. But when you then click "Hide Description" it should reset to its original state, which it doesn´t do now.

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".show_hide").text("Hide Description");
    $(this).prev().prev().prev('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    $(this).prev().prev('.desc_preview').fadeOut();
    $("#fade_layer").fadeOut();
    return false
});
});
```

Is there any way to do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
$('.show-hide').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.description').slideToggle();
  $(this).fadeOut(function() {
    ($(this).html() == 'Show description') ? $(this).html('Hide description'): $(this).html('Show description');
  });
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <div class="description">
    This is a description! Learn all about things inside this paragraph. 'Cause that's what descriptions are for - learning about a person, place or thing!
  </div>
  <button class="show-hide">Show description</button>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="description">
    This is a description! Learn all about things inside this paragraph. 'Cause that's what descriptions are for - learning about a person, place or thing!
  </div>
  <button class="show-hide">Show description</button>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="description">
    This is a description! Learn all about things inside this paragraph. 'Cause that's what descriptions are for - learning about a person, place or thing!
  </div>
  <button class="show-hide">Show description</button>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="description">
    This is a description! Learn all about things inside this paragraph. 'Cause that's what descriptions are for - learning about a person, place or thing!
  </div>
  <button class="show-hide">Show description</button>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="description">
    This is a description! Learn all about things inside this paragraph. 'Cause that's what descriptions are for - learning about a person, place or thing!
  </div>
  <button class="show-hide">Show description</button>
</div>
```